# Convert String to float in c++

Tags: c++, string, boost, floating-point

I want to convert a `std::string` which I read from a csv file to a `float`. There are several float representations included like:

```
0,0728239
6.543.584.399
2,67E-02
```

These string should all be floats. First I used `atof()`, but the conversion was wrong:

```
2,67E-02 -> 2
6.543.584.399 -> 6.543
```

Then I used `boost::lexical_cast<float>()`, but when it comes to a float with an exponent included, it throws following exception

```
`terminate` called after throwing an instance of
`'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'`
`what()`:  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
Aborted
```

What is the best way to get all three types of strings converted to a float?

Comment: perhaps you could show us a sample input showing the various cases?

Comment: @sehe a sample input string is "2,67E-02", "0.0728239" or "6.543.584.399" these values should be converted to floats

Comment: @iam_peter: what is the expected outcome? `6.543.584.399` cannot be valid at the same time as `0.0728239`

Comment: @sehe sorry, my fault. '6.543.584.399' is '6543584399' the comma seperation is a bit messed up

Comment: A locale is how you tell C++ "I'm using `.` to separate the groups of thousands, and `,` to separate the whole part of the fractional part."  By default, C++ will use the `C locale`, which uses `.` to separate the whole part from the fractional part, and doesn't use anything to separate the groups of thousands.  There's a "C++ way" of using locales ( http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_loc0.html ), but nobody uses it and some compilers don't implement it.  The "C way" is pretty straightforward, though.

Comment: @sehe: Incorrect for European countries.  They swapped our comma and decimal in numbers.

Comment: ok, the csv file is faulty, beacause '0.0728239' should be '0,0728239'

Comment: @ iam_peter: o heck. of course :) That makes a lot more sense. @MooingDuck: accidentally upvoted you comment. The point was that the specimen were _inconsistent_ in and of themselves. There is no European locale that supports _that_ (OT: I'm from such a European country myself :))

Comment: @iam_peter: _please_ edit you question to fix the errors?

Comment: @MooingDuck: are you being funny for the sake of it? If so, you can stop because you're causing more confusion. Of course it said something different until 1 hr ago, and you pretty well know that. Incidentally, it's what I _quoted_ in my 'expected outcome' comment question. Sigh.

Comment: @sehe: My appologies.  I'm not trying to be funny.  I'm simply dumb, and failed no notice the leading zero origionally, and then failed to notice he'd corrected it.  Pretty much fail all around.

Comment: Do any of the float-to-string converters actually handle thousands separators (regardless of the particular type of separator)?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Spirit Boost Qi `RealPolicy` is the only thing _I know of_ that does (see the [example here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.real._code__phrase_role__identifier__realpolicies__phrase___code__specializations))

Comment: What would be 6.543 and 6,543? 6543 or 6543e-3?

Answer (score 6):

`scanf` with the correct locale set. Seriously. Save yourself the hassle of doing it the "c++ way" in this case.

Comment: `atof()` is hardly "the C++ way", and works fine once you set the current locale.

Comment: I didn't refer to atof(), but let me add that I think scanf is the way to go as atof does not tell you if it could not parse the string.

Comment: OP was attempting to use `atof`.  You criticize him for "doing it the C++ way".  You do raise a good point about `atof` not telling if it could not parse the string though.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/

> Notice that locale configuration affects the behavior of many
>   functions within the standard C library:   In string.h,
>   functions strcoll and strxfrm are affected by character transformation
>   rules.   In ctype.h, all functions except for isdigit and
>   isxdigit are affected by the extended character set selected.   In
>   stdio.h, formatted input/output operations are affected
>   by character transformation rules and decimal-point character set in
>   the numeric formatting settings.   In time.h, the function
>   strftime is affected by the time formatting settings. In this header,
>   it affects the value returned by its functions setlocale and
>   localeconv.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/

```
setlocale ( LC_NUMERIC, "" ); // "" is the Environment's default locale
```

Then you can use atof, scanf, etc correctly.  However, that's the C way of doing things.  The C++ way is:

```
float stof(const std::string& input) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    float result;
    static std::locale uselocale("") //again, "" is Environment's default locale
    ss.imbue(uselocale);
    ss << input;
    ss >> result;
    return result;
}
```

All compilers must accept these locales: "", "C"
MSVC accepts these locales: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx
(wait, does MSVC `setlocale` really not accept "en_US"?)
GCC accepts these locales: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/localization.html#locale.impl.c

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool isdot(const char &c)
{
    return '.'==c;
}

float to(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), &isdot ),s.end());
    replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ',', '.');


    std::stringstream ss(s);
    float v = 0;
    ss >> v;
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string a1("0,0728239");
    const std::string a2("6.543.584.399");
    const std::string a3("2,67E-02");

    std::cout << to(a1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout << to(a2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout << to(a3)<<std::endl;
}
```

See it [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4b275225582bfbd)